# Vagrant docker-exec

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am running Vagrant on Mac OS X. I have created following Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    config.ssh.insert_key = true
    config.vm.provider "docker" do |doc|
            doc.image = "httpd"
            doc.ports = ["80:80"]
            doc.name = 'apache'
            doc.remains_running = true
            doc.has_ssh = false
    end end
```

It is starting, however I can't execute following command:
vagrant docker-exec -dt apache -- /bin/bash

I have also tried to change apache into container ID, but have failed too.

The container is running as I can check it in Virtualbox. 
I can only see that I have vagrant docker-logs and vagrant docker-run, but the documentation of Vagrant says that there should be docker-exec.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you confirm you're using vagrant 1.8.3+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-i` `--interactive` is required if you want a bash shell you can type in.

`-d` `--detach` will not work for typing either as the process will be in started in the background.

Use `vagrant docker-exec -it apache -- /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that is correct. I also know now that you need to do list-commands to see this docker-exec command.

thank you